# При вставке ошибка: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Подключение к БД на сервере:

```
def connect():
    # Выполняем подключение к серверу Oracle

    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("SYSTEM", 'pass', "172.20.0.2:1521/ORCLCDB")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    return connection, cursor

def load_database(total):
    # Загрузка данных в Oracle

    connection, cursor = connect()

    for article in total:
        sql_article = "INSERT INTO ARTICLES (NAME) VALUES ('%s')"% 
        (article['name_article'])
        cursor.execute(sql_article)
        connection.commit()
```

При выполнении кода:

```
cursor.execute(sql_article)
```

приложение зависает. Если прервать выполнение, получаем ошибку:

> cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Если же отправить этот запрос в БД не из цикла, то все работает.

В чем проблема?

Comment: A что у вас в total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 01013, 00000, "user requested cancel of current operation"

Это ошибка носит информационный характер - произошло прерывание текущей операции, она будет закончена с откатом изменений, каких либо действий не требуется и можно продолжать дальше.

---

Почему вставка длится так долго?

1. Не стоит делать массовую вставку новых записей в цикле, это долго.
2. Надо использовать переменные связывания вместо литеральных значений. Каждая вставка как в вопросе проходит парсинг заново (*hard parse*), что очень долго.

Исходя из вышеизложенного, код вставки будет выгядеть как-то так:

```py
total = [{"no":123, "name":"art123"}, {"no":222, "name":"art222"}]

cursor.executemany ("insert into art (name) values (:1)", [(d['name'],) for d in total])
connection.commit ()
```